# Count number of features that matches a (minimum) value for each group (id)

Tags: fme-form, statistics

## Context

In [FME](https://www.safe.com/fme) I want to count for each group (defined by a "group by" `id` in any kind of aggregation-like transformer, such as the StatisticsCalculator), how many occurrences equal to a certain value can be found in a field (aka attribute).

In my situation, I'd like to figure out how many values in a field named `hour` matches the minimum and `06` (in most of the records, (i.e. rows), but not necessarily for all, `06` is the minimum) for each `id` group.

The StatisticsCalculator can compute the minimum for each group, but I'm not able to figure out how to actually count how many values match this, neither how many values match a given one, e.g. 06`.

## Sample

```
group_id hour
       1    6
       1    6
       1    6
       1    7
       2    7
       2    7
       2    7
       2    9
       3    6
       3    6 
       3    7
       3    8
```

## Desired outputs

This table:

```
group_id hour_min count
       1        6     3  
       2        7     3 
       3        6     2
```

and this one:

```
group_id hour_eq6_count
       1              3  
       2              0
       3              2
```

or this single one:

```
group_id hour_eq6_count hour_min hour_min_count
       1              3        6              3
       2              0        7              3
       3              2        6              2
```

Comment: What version of FME?

Answer (score 3):

You can probably achieve the results you want by aggregating the features and grouping by group_id using the [Aggregator](http://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_Desktop_Documentation/FME_Transformers/Transformers/aggregator.htm) transformer. Ensure to store the results into a list.

From there, you can analyse the lists using combinations of [ListStatisticsCalculator](https://hub.safe.com/publishers/pacific-spatial-solutions/transformers/liststatisticscalculator), [ListRangeExtractor](http://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_Desktop_Documentation/FME_Transformers/Transformers/listrangeextractor.htm) and [Tester](http://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_Desktop_Documentation/FME_Transformers/Transformers/tester.htm) transformers.

Alternatively, you could write some python code to analyse the attributes using a [PythonCaller](http://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_Desktop_Documentation/FME_Transformers/Transformers/pythoncaller.htm), which, depending on your Python skills may be easier.

Answer (score 3):

So currently you're calculating the minimum value, and want to know how many there are. I think it's easier to do it the other way around: find how many of all records there are of each, then look for the minimum.

So first calculate the number of records per value...

i.e.

- Place a StatisticsCalculator

  - Group by group_id and hour
  - Analyze hour
  - Get the Total Count statistic

[image]

Now we know the number of records per value, but unfortunately the order is messed up. So let's sort the data...

- Add a Sorter

  - Sort by: group_id, Numeric, Ascending
  - Sort by: hour, Numeric, Ascending

[image]

Now we have the data sorted in order of lowest first, and any duplicate group record can be removed because it isn't the lowest hour...

- Add a DuplicateFilter

  - Filter by group_id

[image]

Note that it's the StatisticsCalculator:Summary port that we're using, not the Complete.